# Generate endpoints in separate classes with swager-codegen

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have below YAML for **swagger-codegen** and I want it to generate this endpoints in two separate classes, by default it generates one api class with both endpoints,  is it s way to mark them as separate api?

```
/tenants:
post:
  produces:
    - application/json
  consumes:
    - application/json
  parameters:
    - name: body
      in: body
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/TenantRequest"

#################### User ####################

/tenants/{tenantId}/users:
post:
  description: Create a User
  produces:
    - application/json
  consumes:
    - application/json
  parameters:
    - name: tenantId
      in: path
      required: true
      type: string
    - name: body
      in: body
      description: User object
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/UserRequest"
```

Comment: This is done in the `addOperationToGroup` method at DefaultCodegen.java called by `processOperation` method at DefaultGeneratr.java, if you create your own client you can override the first one to put them into different operation groups (and therefor classes). But I don't think there is an easy way if you want to keep those endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate APIs to be created then you need to change `/tenants:` to `/createTenants:`

say for example you have 2 operations.

```
/user/add
/user/delete
```

If you try to generate API classes for the above operation then it will create class named `UserApi` with `add` and `delete` methods in it.

Now if you want separate API classes for `add` and `delete` then you need to change the end point as follows.

```
/addUser
/deleteUser
```

Comment: I got this but the question - is it a way to generate separate classes for the endpoints with the same beginning. As I would have CRUD for tenants and CRUD for tenants/id/users and I do not want to store them in one class.